# Batch requests for angular 2 applications

Tags: angular, http

I have a survey application where users can log in and out as they please and answer questions.

There are 3 common scenarios that I can think of:
1) User logs in for the 1st time and answers questions
2) User logs in for the nth time changes previous answers and answers new questions
3) User logs in for the nth time does not change previous answer but answers new questions

My question: Does something need to be set up on the backend so that I do not need to make a HTTP request every time a user answers a new question or changes their answer to a previously answered question?

I think this has something to do with batch requests, but I am not familiar with the subject.

My code uses just standard http requests to get, post, patch, etc

```
  saveAnswers(answers: Answer[]) {
    // this.answers.push(answer);
    const body = JSON.stringify(answers);
    const headers = new Headers({'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3004/answers', body, {headers: headers})
      .map((response: Response) => response.json())
      .catch((error: Response) => Observable.throw(error.json()));
  }
```

Thanks!

Comment: What do you have so far? (Can you show the code you have so far?)

Comment: I just edited it @Tezra

Comment: Instead of saving just an {Object}, I want to save an array of objects. [Object, Object, Object]